# What is the key file for ssldump?

Tags: ssl, tcpdump, packet-sniffer, tshark

I search google for a tool to decode `https` traffic and get the `ssldump` with examples like:

```
ssldump -k xxx.pem  -i eth0 -d host example.com
```

I wonder what the key file `xxx.pem` is. On the server hosting example.com, the file is what is specified by `SSLCertificateKeyFile` in `httpd.conf`, right?(but I have no luck decrypting the traffic on server using that key file). On client side, what file should I use as the key file? If I want to decrypt the traffic between my machine and https://google.com, I certainly cannot get the private key for google.com. And I don't think a client uses a private key file to encrypt/decrypt the data in `https`.

Comment: Make sure that key file contains only private key. Make sure that the captured file contains ssl handshake as well

Comment: @kofemann The key file is issued by letsencrypt. All content is contained within -----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY----- and -----END PRIVATE KEY-----. From the ServerHello message, I can see the cipherSuite is TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256. Does ssldump support that cipherSuite?